# A countable set theory providing choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

Instead of Zermelo set theory $Z$ take $Y$ = $Z$ minus the power set axiom plus

Enumerability: $\forall x(x\neq \emptyset \to\exists f[f:\mathbb{N}\overset{onto}{\frown}x ])$

$\imath$ is the definite description operator so that  $\imath$x(x is the number of acting US presidents) = 1. $\mu$ is the least operator, so that 0=$\mu$(+<1) in number theory.

Let M be an infinite set in Y of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets. Let $f$ be a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to M.  Let $h$ be a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\bigcup M$. Define:

$\forall i(g(i)\overset{def}{=} \imath x\exists m(\langle m,x\rangle\in h\wedge m=\mu n(\langle n,x\rangle\in h\wedge x\in f(i)))$

I state without giving a proof:

$\mathbf{Theorem} \ G=\{x|\exists i(i\in \mathbb{N}\wedge \langle i,x\rangle\in g\}$ contains precisely one member from each of the members of $M$.

Has this been looked at, and is it otherwise worthwhile pursuing if one as me has reservations towards the power set?

Comment: In definition of $x$, maybe $x \in f(i)$ should be out of $\mu$ operator? Maybe lack a parenthesis after $h$, inside $\mu$ operator.

Comment: Frankly I found the notation made this question much harder to follow.  But let me see if I've understood correctly.  Let $M$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets, which by your axiom has an enumeration $M=\{M_1, M_2,\dots\}$.  Likewise, there is an enumeration of $\bigcup M = \{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$.  Your claim is we can choose one element from each $M_i$, simply by choosing the element which occurs first in the enumeration $\{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$.  Is that right?

Comment: It is well-known that AC is equivalent to the well-ordering principle over ZF.  You just stated a more specific version of the well-ordering principle in ZF - powerset.  More generally one could assert that every set is the image of a function on an ordinal.

Comment: @Nate Eldrigde I believe what you state is a fair rendering in natural language. Each g(i) is the x in f(i) which occurs first in h; isn't that right?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Yes, there are these equivalences of the AC, and I am glad you point to well-ordering as a near version. My main concern here is that Enumerability is a very reasonable alternative to the power set axiom which postulates inscrutable entities, given the LS-theorem and large degree of non-absoluteness. I was surprised that choice may be a bonus. I am also interested in the strength of these theories with Enumerability instead of power set, especially when related to the Reverse Mathematics Program.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Well you can just work in 2nd order arithmetic, where everything is countable.  On the other hand, it is a very mainstream position to treat the collection of all real numbers as an object capable of being used in constructions just like anything else.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I like to be able to offer new ways of looking at things, and am skeptical towards the existence of a set of all real numbers. Perhaps $ZF-Power+Enumerability$ is sufficient to capture enough of second order number theory to be a foundation for mathematics.

Comment: I don’t see how a position can be a foundation for mathematics if it excludes large areas of modern mathematics.

Comment: @MonroeEskew There are many points of view on what mathamatics is and should be. Confer the Foundations of mathematics email list for many recent discussions. Soloman Feferman's article A Little Bit Goes a Long Way is good on this. For a long time many have opted for weak systems, also in light of the Reverse Mathematics Program. Skolem, Weyl and others were skeptical towards classical set theory and Fraenkel suggested Second Order Arithmetics as sufficient for Analysis. Nelson opted for a weak predicative system on a par with Robinson's Q. Computable mathematics is at the level of RCA(0).

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal You can have a philosophical view on what mathematics should be.  But what mathematics *is* is a more factual question. The goal of “providing a foundation for mathematics” is a utilitarian one, and we should be able to check whether your preferred system succeeds at formalizing mathematics as it actually is.

Comment: @MonroeEskew What is a philosophical view? There is no such thing as what mathematics really is. All those I listed are influential mathematicians. The utility of mathematics lies in its ability to support computations. I suggest we discuss this further elsewhere, if at all.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I just mean look at the actual practice of mathematics.

Comment: @MonroeEskew As I have pointed out and as you may see if you will look, there are many mathematical practices. I am surprised that you seem to think otherwise.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal But you are choosing to privilege one kind above others-- those that deny uncountable sets.  So ZF-powerset+countability could be a foundation for "*a kind of* mathematics", not simply a foundation for mathematics--unless you insist on interpreting all the uncountable mathematics as people talking about countable models of ZFC or similar theories.

Comment: Frode, I agree that *a* foundation for mathematics need not be a foundation for *all* ordinary mathematics. But I disagree with the comment that "many have *opted for* weak systems in light of Reverse Mathematics" -- so far as I know, most people significantly influenced by Reverse Mathematics regard the various theories formalistically, without opting for one over another. E.g. Feferman was advocating predicative foundations even before there was reverse mathematics; and Simpson does not advocate one foundation.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I am not seeking to privilege anyone, and believers in uncountable sets have been privileged for too long. Beyond RCA(0) all things mathematical are becoming unclear. My theory W is probably close to PI(1-2)-comprehension, and perhaps above, which is more than sufficient for science and speculative purposes. In general it is a good precept to be satisfied with as weak mathematical systems as possible, as they are safer.

Comment: @MattF. I agree, but only up to a point. Simpson e.g. recently pointed out in lecture: "Our message is that, if mathematicians exercise some care and work within the strictures of the known “weak” systems or other systems which are finitistically reducible, then all is well. The finitistic core is protected from contamination. Hilbert’s program lives!"

I forgot to include Per Martin Löf and Vladimir Voevodsky in my miniscule survey, by the was. Many in the proof theoretic traditions have been skeptical towards uncountability, by the way.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal So what is the source of your skepticism?  Is it the consistency strength of the powerset axiom, or just some metaphysical qualm?  Because your system does not preclude accommodating very high strength assumptions like, "there is a countable transitive model of ZFC + a huge cardinal."

Comment: I already adduced LS, and this was also the reason for Skolem's skepticism. Of course, *if* ZFC + a measurable cardinal has a model then it can be accommodated in my system. There are other problems as with what Feferman called "monsters", e.g. the Banach-Tarski "paradox".

Comment: Yet Skolem’s paradox lives on in your system!  Your system may countenance countable models that believe they are uncountable.  Also your system may countenance models that believe in paradoxical decompositions of the unit ball.  How are these things even possible?!  I don’t see how you have alleviated the headache.

Comment: @MonroeEskew No, the system does not say that there are uncountable infinities! As I stated, *if* the systems are consistent they have countable models in my system. There is no problem, and systems can have all kinds of countable models *if* consistent.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I’m not sure you can claim the Skolem paradox as a motivation for your system, when you don’t seem to find it paradoxical at all. The reason it is supposed to be perplexing is that there can be a model of classical set theory which is wrong about countability.  I don’t see how you make Banach-Tarski any less perplexing either.

Comment: For example: I do not believe that $ZF$ is inconsistent, but I believe that $ZF$ has no standard model.